# Rust and Domain-Driven Design to make certain errors impossible to write

Tags: rust, functional-programming, domain-driven-design

I'm struggling with how I might implement something in Rust that is pretty straightforward in, say, TypeScript. Essentially a **sum type of product types that enforces business rules at compile-time**.

Suppose I have a struct `Location` that holds two properties, `state` and `city`, where `state: StateEnum` and `city: String`.

Generally, `city` and `state` can hold any `StateEnum`/`String`, respectively. So far, so good:

```rust
struct Location {
  state: StateEnum,
  city: String,
}
```

However, there are business rules that make it so certain values of `state` restrict the validity of certain `city`. Obviously you cannot have a valid `Location { state: StateEnum::TX, city: "New York City }`.

In OOP you'd make `city` private and have `setCity` check and throw an exception if the city wasn't legal for that state to enforce the business rule. A runtime exception.

In FP you have the ability to write your types so it's something like

```js
type NYLocation = {
  state: NY
  city: 'Albany' | 'NYC' ...
}

type TexasLocation = { ... }

type Location = NYLocation | TexasLocation | ...
```

and your IDE would warn you that you cannot set TexasLocation.city to `newCity: string` without first using a type guard in your code to narrow the possible values from `string` to `'Houston' | 'Austin' | ...`.

Is there a way (I mean, obviously there has to be a way; is there an *idiomatic* way to make this compile-time in Rust instead of run-time like OOP has?

Comment: I'm a bit perplexed by your wording. Your "OOP" solution is not OOP related at all, and actually you could implement it in Rust or in C, and it does not take advantage of OOP patterns. Similarly, I fail to see how your FP solution is FP at all. Most FP languages do not even allow you to have string-based enums (ie. `'Albany' | 'NYC' | ...`), just regular enums. I think that the solution proposed by @cdhowie would be the one chosen if programming in a FP language too. Finally, I don't see how is this related to DDD...

Comment: Something feels off to me here. I would generally load the list of cities in each state, and maybe even the list of states, from some kind of dataset at runtime. I would also expect that the values are assigned at runtime – you generally get those from user input or geo IP localization or whatever, and you don't spell out "New York City" as a value in your source code. So in practice, wouldn't this need to be some kind of runtime error anyway?

Comment: @SvenMarnach Yes, with TS I would probably hard-code the states as an enum or sum type of strings, because it's such a short list. Then I'd move the cities into a JSON or something, and when you read from it, cast it to something like `type City = { readonly City: unique symbol }` and then cast values read from the file as `City`or `TexasCity` or something. But I don't think you can read and cast like that with Rust.

Comment: You are making it to complicated. Just have an unmutable `Location` type and a factory method or repository. Want get a city? call the repository, fetch it from the DB. Didn't find it there? Then its not valid. Db would have all valid state & city combinations. Just need to make sure that `Location` can't be constructed outside of the factory/repository function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To a degree, yes.  You can statically enforce a domain of discrete values with an enum, as you're already doing with states.  You just have to extend that concept to cities.

You could have an enum for each state's cities and have `Location` instead be an enum.

```
enum NewYorkCities {
    Albany,
    NewYorkCity,
    // ...
}

enum WashingtonCities {
    Seattle,
    Olympia,
    // ...
}

enum Location {
    NewYork(NewYorkCities),
    Washington(WashingtonCities),
    // ...
}
```

This gives you the ability to prove that values not in the given domain cannot exist in the program.

Finally, you just need a way to convert each enum to and from strings.  These kinds of functions can be generated by macros in the [`strum`](https://docs.rs/strum/0.13.0/strum/) crate.

Obviously this requires recompilation to alter the acceptable domain, but you'd have the same problem with the TypeScript code anyway, so I assume that's an acceptable drawback.

Comment: Actually with TypeScript you could define a tagged type like `type City = string & { readonly City: unique symbol }` and then read from a CSV and just cast each value to `City` or `TexasCity` or whatever. Any non-programmer could update the CSV with new cities. Then you'd have your sum type of "strings" representing a state's cities. Can't do that with enums and Rust, too bad. :/ This is exactly how I'd do it with TS and reading data from a flat file.

Comment: @user1713450 That's a different type than you asked about in your question, and that wouldn't necessarily strictly enforce anything at compile-time like you were asking about.

Comment: Yeah I think I've confused myself by not breaking two questions into two posts. I haven't gotten clarification from the answers I've gotten, so I'm wondering if I should delete (versus close) and ask what I'm asking better. Ultimately I tried to simplify my actual issue with the state/city thing, when really it's more like "only this one Foo can pair with this Bar, but generally any Foo can pair with any Bar, how can I idiomatically write code to enforce that one Foo/Bar but also express all other Foo/Bar pairs are pairable in general"

Comment: you answered my poorly-put question well, so I decided to keep it and mark your answer correct so you'd get the credit